# Publishing .NET Core 3.1 React application on IIS 8.5 results in API routes not being respected

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm currently trying to mount a .NET Core 3.1 MVC application created with `dotnet new react`. The application works perfectly fine when running it via Visual Studio Code. However, when publishing with `dotnet publish -c Release -r win81-x64` and mounting the application in IIS 8.5, the routes for the APIs stop working, sending all requests to the React page.

Currently my configuration in `Startup.cs` looks like this:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
}
```

And the code in a test controller I made looks like this:

```cs
namespace Application.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase {

        private readonly ILogger<TestController> _logger;

        public TestController(ILogger<TestController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetTest()
        {
            return "Test";
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried creating a new React project and mounting it, and that does seem to work. However, the `Startup.cs` file has the exact same configuration, so I can't find anything to modify on my application.

Comment: `the routes for the APIs stop working, sending all requests to the React page.` Do you mean that react client app works well, but API not response correctly while you make request to endpoint from browser address bar?

Comment: @FeiHan The react app works, but all the API responses return the React page instead of the appropiate JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out the first version I uploaded had some issues that prevented routes from working properly, and while I immediately fixed it, the Service Worker that the default .NET project has cached the broken API point as part of the site. Apparently this bypasses having the 'Disable Cache' tick box in developer tools.